# When to deregister a java/android object from another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

In OO I think it is not uncommon for an object to register itself with another object (perhaps a singleton) for callbacks.

In C++ I think it is not uncommon to do this registration in the constructor or super class constructor of the object being registered and to do the deregistration its the destructor.  This gives some assurances for the right timing.

I have two questions.  What is the best strategy to achieve this in Java in general, given the lack of a destructor?  In android, if the object is just a member of an activity or a fragment, I guess the object should be registered and deregistered from within two of the on... methods in the activity or the fragment.  I think it may be hard to know exactly when the object will be destroyed.  Which 2 on... methods in an activity or in a fragment would be best to use for this?

Additionally, perhaps less common, if the object is referenced from a number of other objects can one decide to deregister on the basis it is going out of scope and how or can one only deregister it based on some other state that just implies you are on balance probably happy to no longer receive call backs?

Comment: The ondestroy method will actually clean the object for you, but if the object is still in use and the said fragment is already destroy and you just got youreself a memory leak.

Comment: OK, so if the object is a member of a fragment or an activity, deregister it from the other object in fragment or activity ondestroy and after the call to ondestroy the reference to it in fragment or activity is bound to be gone, right?

Comment: Is the call to fragment or activity ondestroy guaranteed?

Comment: you dont need to call the ondestroy as it will be called when a backbutton is pressed or when the activity is finished. and yes referenced objects will be gone just like a destructor in c++ automatically without having any code in there.

Comment: No, I realise it's the framework that (potentially) calls it and not just on back button.  What I am asking is, is ondestroy "guatenteed to be called before the activity (or fragment) is actually destroyed and is the activity (or fragment) guaranteed to be actually destroyed after the call to ondestroy?